# How to create a variadic function that are recursive with the given pseudo code in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates, variadic

I am trying to make a recursive variadic template function that works in the following example. The example shows no practicality and is only used to help better understand what I'm asking. So, basically I have a function that takes an infinite amount of parameters of the same type and it recursively calls itself with all but the last parameters. Then, once it finally reaches two parameters the next unction serves as the termination of the function. I know the answer isn't trivial and I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what to do. Any help or direction would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
template <typename... Ts>
void test(int& a, int& b, Ts&... ts){
    test(a, b, ... ); //all but the last parameter

    //last parameter argument is processed here

}

void test(int& a, int& b){
    //end of recursion
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 6;
    int d = 4;

    test(a, b, c, d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to peel parameters from the end of the pack instead of the front?

Comment: Is it possible to make a recursion with all but the first parameter? That's simple: `test(b, ts );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can forward the arguments in a tuple and decrement the index:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
void test_helper(Tuple&& tuple)
{
    if constexpr (I != 0) {
        test_helper<I - 1>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
    }

    // for example
    process(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)));
}

template <typename... Args>
void test(Args&&... args)
{
    test_helper<sizeof...(Args) - 1>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void process(const T& arg)
{
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
}

template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
void test_helper(Tuple&& tuple)
{
    process(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)));

    if constexpr (I != 0) {
        test_helper<I - 1>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
    }
}

template <typename... Args>
void test(Args&&... args)
{
    test_helper<sizeof...(Args) - 1>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main()
{
    test(1, '2', "3", 4.0);
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QKbvFzY9BtgvXCRf))

---

For now, prefer handling arguments from left to right, which is much simpler:

```
template <typename... Args>
void test(Args&&... args)
{
    ((void)process(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
}
```

Handling from right to left will get easier with [P1858 Generalized pack declaration and usage](https://wg21.link/p1858), which unfortunately hasn't been adopted yet:

```
template <typename... Args>
void test(Args&&... args)
{
    test(std::forward<Args>(args)...[:-1]...);

    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) != 0) {
        process(std::forward<Args>(args)...[-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have an example of the initial running in main? I can't seem to compile it with the example I had in main. Thanks! edit - it does compile fine with nothing in main btw

Comment: @Dalton The previous answer was bad anyway; I've updated the answer with a better solution and a full example.